# How to put a link that it go to a page with embedded template too?

Tags: prestashop

I'm following the prestashop tutorial on how to create a PrestaShop 1.7 module. The problem is that it does not work correctly, because I put a link in the left column of the home page, but then, the link goes to a page with no template, with plain text.

All the code is in prestashop docs, I didn't change anything. For this reason, i don't know what happening.

mymodule.php, in the root

```
<?php
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
{
  exit;
}

class MyModule extends Module
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->name = 'mymodule';
    $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
    $this->version = '1.0.0';
    $this->author = 'Firstname Lastname';
    $this->need_instance = 0;
    $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);
    $this->bootstrap = true;

    parent::__construct();

    $this->displayName = $this->l('My module');
    $this->description = $this->l('Description of my module.');

    $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');

    if (!Configuration::get('MYMODULE_NAME'))
      $this->warning = $this->l('No name provided');
  }

  public function install()
    {
      if (Shop::isFeatureActive())
        Shop::setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_ALL);

      if (!parent::install() ||
        !$this->registerHook('leftColumn') ||
        !$this->registerHook('header') ||
        !Configuration::updateValue('MYMODULE_NAME', 'my friend')
      )
        return false;

      return true;
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
      if (!parent::uninstall() ||
        !Configuration::deleteByName('MYMODULE_NAME')
      )
        return false;

      return true;
    }

    public function getContent()
    {
        $output = null;

        if (Tools::isSubmit('submit'.$this->name))
        {
            $my_module_name = strval(Tools::getValue('MYMODULE_NAME'));
            if (!$my_module_name
              || empty($my_module_name)
              || !Validate::isGenericName($my_module_name))
                $output .= $this->displayError($this->l('Invalid Configuration value'));
            else
            {
                Configuration::updateValue('MYMODULE_NAME', $my_module_name);
                $output .= $this->displayConfirmation($this->l('Settings updated'));
            }
        }
        return $output.$this->displayForm();
    }

    public function displayForm()
    {
        // Get default language
        $default_lang = (int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');

        // Init Fields form array
        $fields_form[0]['form'] = array(
            'legend' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Settings'),
            ),
            'input' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('Configuration value'),
                    'name' => 'MYMODULE_NAME',
                    'size' => 20,
                    'required' => true
                )
            ),
            'submit' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Save'),
                'class' => 'btn btn-default pull-right'
            )
        );

        $helper = new HelperForm();

        // Module, token and currentIndex
        $helper->module = $this;
        $helper->name_controller = $this->name;
        $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
        $helper->currentIndex = AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name;

        // Language
        $helper->default_form_language = $default_lang;
        $helper->allow_employee_form_lang = $default_lang;

        // Title and toolbar
        $helper->title = $this->displayName;
        $helper->show_toolbar = true;        // false -> remove toolbar
        $helper->toolbar_scroll = true;      // yes - > Toolbar is always visible on the top of the screen.
        $helper->submit_action = 'submit'.$this->name;
        $helper->toolbar_btn = array(
            'save' =>
            array(
                'desc' => $this->l('Save'),
                'href' => AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name.'&save'.$this->name.
                '&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
            ),
            'back' => array(
                'href' => AdminController::$currentIndex.'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
                'desc' => $this->l('Back to list')
            )
        );

        // Load current value
        $helper->fields_value['MYMODULE_NAME'] = Configuration::get('MYMODULE_NAME');

        return $helper->generateForm($fields_form);
    }

    public function hookDisplayLeftColumn($params)
        {
            $this->context->smarty->assign(
                array(
                    'my_module_name' => Configuration::get('MYMODULE_NAME'),
                    'my_module_link' => $this->context->link->getModuleLink('mymodule', 'display'),
                    'my_module_message' => $this->l('This is a simple text message') // Do not forget to enclose your strings in the l() translation method
                )
            );

            return $this->display(__FILE__, 'mymodule.tpl');
        }

    public function hookDisplayRightColumn($params)
    {
      return $this->hookDisplayLeftColumn($params);
    }

    public function hookDisplayHeader()
    {
      $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'css/mymodule.css', 'all');
    }
}
```

the controller, called display.php in controller/front :

```
<?php
class mymoduledisplayModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
  public function initContent()
  {
    parent::initContent();
    $this->setTemplate('module:mymodule/views/templates/front/display.tpl');
  }
}

?>
```

The display.tpl is only a text, because I understood (according to the guide) it's not necessary now add include of header and footer

display.tpl:

```
Welcome to my shop!
```

[I would like obtain something like this](http://doc.prestashop.com/download/attachments/9076773/09-embeddedTemplate.PNG?version=2&modificationDate=1366278794000&api=v2)

(with the actual version of prestashop, in the image show it a old version)

[But I obtain this](https://gyazo.com/c175e25d0bfb260cfbf5cb8b69bccfab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the documentation is obsolete in a lot of parts so probably that example is out of the date. To reach your goal in the current version you need to extend a `page.tpl` file in your `front/display.tpl` and override the default `{block name="page_content"}` with your data. You should get something like this in your `display.tpl`:

```
{extends file='page.tpl'}
{block name="page_content"}
    Welcome to my shop!
{/block}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought I would go crazy hehe